# Not able to create directory under /var/log as root user

Tags: unix, hadoop

What could be the reason for the following erorrs. I ran the script as a root user. I believe the root user must be having super user permissions. It was failing with the following error

> mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/hadoop’: Permission denied

```
(base) [root@localhost ~]# cat /tmp/hadoop-service-startup.log
STARTING NAMENODE
WARNING: HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS has been replaced by HDFS_NAMENODE_OPTS. Using value of HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS.
WARNING: /var/log/hadoop does not exist. Creating.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/hadoop’: Permission denied
ERROR: Unable to create /var/log/hadoop. Aborting.
COMPLETE
STARTING SECONDARY NAMENODE
WARNING: HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS has been replaced by HDFS_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS. Using value of HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS.
WARNING: /var/log/hadoop does not exist. Creating.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/hadoop’: Permission denied
ERROR: Unable to create /var/log/hadoop. Aborting.
COMPLETE
STARTING DATANODE
WARNING: HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS has been replaced by HDFS_DATANODE_OPTS. Using value of HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS.
WARNING: /var/log/hadoop does not exist. Creating.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/hadoop’: Permission denied
ERROR: Unable to create /var/log/hadoop. Aborting.
COMPLETE
STARTED DAEMONS
4884 Jps
STARTING RESOURCEMANGER
WARNING: /var/log/hadoop does not exist. Creating.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/hadoop’: Permission denied
ERROR: Unable to create /var/log/hadoop. Aborting.
COMPLETE
STARTING NODEMANGER
WARNING: /var/log/hadoop does not exist. Creating.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/hadoop’: Permission denied
ERROR: Unable to create /var/log/hadoop. Aborting.
COMPLETE
STARTING HISTORYSERVER
WARNING: /var/log/hadoop does not exist. Creating.
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/log/hadoop’: Permission denied
ERROR: Unable to create /var/log/hadoop. Aborting.
COMPLETE
STARTED DAEMONS
5012 Jps
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be having a permissions issue. Try changing the permissions doing the following

```
  sudo chown -R hadoop /var/log/hadoop/
```

If thy doesn’t work, you could try to work around it by changing the location of the Hadoop logs to a different location

Comment: hmm, root user must be having all the permissions , isnt it ? or ?

Comment: getting the other error, hadoop user doesnt seem present